# Access to list elements in R

Tags: r, list

I have got a list of 1300 lists in R. Something like this example:

```
Example = list(list(A = 1, B=data.frame(x = 2, y = 2), C="Test"), list(A = 2, B=data.frame(x = 1, y = 2), C="Test2"), list(A = 3, B=data.frame(x = 3, y = 8), C="Test3"))

> Beispiel
[[1]]
[[1]]$A
[1] 1

[[1]]$B
  x y
1 2 2

[[1]]$C
[1] "Test"

[[2]]
[[2]]$A
[1] 2

[[2]]$B
  x y
1 1 2

[[2]]$C
[1] "Test2"

[[3]]
[[3]]$A
[1] 3

[[3]]$B
  x y
1 3 8

[[3]]$C
[1] "Test3"
```

Now, I need a `data.frame` like this:

```
 rbind(Beispiel[[1]]$B, Beispiel[[2]]$B, Beispiel[[3]]$B)
```

The problem is, that it does not work with a command like

```
 rbind(Beispiel[[1:3]]$B)
```

**Any idea how I can get a data.frame without naming every list?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over the list using `lapply` to extract the desired element of each sublist:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(Example, "[[", "B"))
#  x y
#1 2 2
#2 1 2
#3 3 8
```

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr`, if you pass a `map` function a string (or integer), it will use it as an extractor to select nodes with that index. Further, if you use `map_df`, it will coerce the results to a data.frame, so all you need would be:

```
library(purrr)

map_df(Example, 'B')
##   x y
## 1 2 2
## 2 1 2
## 3 3 8
```